# Sequelize.Close once program complete reading all data

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I have this scrip that read from an object array and load it to a MS SQL database, without the Sequelize.close the code seems to be stuck waiting on the next object, when there is none exist. I would like to close the connection once its done reading the object array.

```
 async.eachSeries(grouparrobj,(item,cb) =>{
        async.each(item,(items,callback)=>{

            var queryvar = `INSERT INTO ${tablename} (ID,NAME) VALUES ('${items.ID}','${items.name}')`;
            sequelize.query(queryvar).then(results =>{
                callback();

            })
        },(err,result) =>{
            if (err)
            {
            console.log('Error',err);
            }
            else{
                console.log(`Finished processing level ${item}`)
                cb();  

            }
        })

    , (err,success) => cb(err,success);


    })
```

How do i achieve this

Comment: Not sure what the most correct answer is, but I've been using `process.exit()` for some simple scripts.

Comment: I found an alternate way to do it. I moved the asyn each to another function and pass the callback there and close the sequelize connection

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate way to do it. I moved the asyn each to another function and pass the callback there and close the sequelize connection